# How do i get make session id from a loop of mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning php and i need some help in one of my project.
How can i get id of a specific row while displaying the value of other column (in my case title) from a loop so that i can make it `$SESSION` and forward it to next page.

For now what i want to do is get an id of the row when i click the title and show the post in the next page and work further on it. I think i can use javascript for but don't know how to do so.

My codes (by which i am currently fetching data from database)

```
<div class="list-group">
     <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a>
     <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but have you thought about what happens if two posts have the same title? I think what you have won't handle that case cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Assume view_page.php is the page you want to view content of that row on when you click the row and you will use get method to extract id to go fetch content of a specific row in your database.

" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-dark">

on url address you will see something like after view_page.php?id=1

use this coode to get that row id: `$id = $_GET['id'];`